# InstallShield custom action on major update

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShield and trying to execute a shell script (Custom Action) when my setup.exe is in Major upgrade mode.
I'm kind of sure that the setup indeed runs in MAJOR UPGRADE mode as it first uninstalls the installed version and then installs the setup.exe version.

However, the action I added under `Behavior and Logic` doesn't happen...
I set the `Install UI Sequence` as `<First Action>` and `install UI Condition` as `IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE` but nothing..

Where in the Sequence should I insert my custom action (after which sequence) if I want it to take place during major upgrade process and right at beginning of the uninstall (before the install of the updated version)?

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **When a setup is uninstalled as part of a major upgrade it runs in silent mode**. This means there is no GUI and the actions you have
>   inserted in the InstallUISequence sequence will never run - in
>   technical terms the whole InstallUISequence is skipped, and only the
>   InstallExecuteSequence runs.

We need to know what your action is doing to provide correct advice. Is it making changes to the system, or is it just displaying information or requesting user input? If your custom action makes changes to the system it should be inserted in the InstallExecuteSequence and not in the InstallUISequence at all (no changes should be made to a system from the UI sequence). In other cases you should insert the custom action into both sequences - it all depends on what it is doing. Are you using Installshield Express btw?

Your condition of `IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE` should work, but you can also use `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` which is the built-in condition in Windows Installer, the former is InstallShield's own, custom condition I believe. I would prefer the standard, Windows Installer property.

> However, you should be aware that the condition `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`
>   is not true in the installing setup, only in the uninstalling setup. I
>   believe IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE is valid in the installing setup, but
>   not in the uninstalling setup. It could be set in both - I am not
>   sure. [See similar issue in the context of WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090120/129130).

For a convenient chart of custom action conditions please see this PDF from Flexera (makers of InstallShield): **https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf**. I have not tested these conditions, please test thoroughly.

**Erroneous conditioning which makes custom actions run at unexpected times is very common**. Please analyze closely when the action should actually run. If it should run on every uninstall (regardless whether it is an uninstall initiated by a major upgrade or a manual uninstall), a better condition might be: `REMOVE~="ALL"` (valid for all uninstalls). Personally I like to add `NOT PATCH` to all my conditions to prevent all custom actions from running in patch mode (which I find is rarely desired). Try the linked chart above to help you decide on your conditioning.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please remember to not make changes to the system using immediate mode custom actions from the setup GUI - these actions will all be skipped in silent mode and your install will be incomplete when run silently. The setup will also fail for regular users running your MSI install with elevated rights (permission denied for immediate mode actions). For details please read: [**section 10 in this answer** (and also the linked answer from that section)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution).