# How to skip "ConfigureIIs" action while major upgrade in WIX

Tags: iis, wix

I am trying to upgrade IIS websites by keeping old IIS setting as it is.
I found same question but didn't find any satisfying answer.

SO after long research I found that "ConfigureIIs" action removing Old IIS websites, now I want to skip this action.

`<Custom Action="ConfigureIIs" After="InstallFiles">(&amp;Web = 3)</Custom>`
This I have tried.

please provide solution.

Comment: You might learn how to use PowerShell script to do so and then call PowerShell from MSI. I don't think WiX exposes all IIS related API for customization.

Comment: Windows Installer sets [`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgradingproductcode) property when a product gets removed due to a major upgrade.

Comment: For the record: `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` is set in the old setup being uninstalled during a major upgrade (not in the newer version being installed), `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` is set in a setup if it detects that an older version is being uninstalled / upgraded as part of a major upgrade process. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090120/129130).

Answer (score 0):

The [WebSite element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/website.html) has a ConfigureIfExists attribute that I typically set to No.   That's met my needs nicely.  Would that work for you?

The way I use it is I install a site knowing it'll conflict with the default website and not start.  Then I have the webmaster configure it with port / host headers / SSL certs per his specific needs  and start the site.   Future upgrades leave all of this intact.

Comment: I tried It ConfigureIfExists="no", even that didnt work for me.