# How do I install files with WiX Toolset that are not tracked by Windows Installer Resiliency checks

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using WiX Toolset for installing a program. I have some files in the program I want to install for users and never overwrite or uninstall them. The users may modify these files because they are templates and I don't want them changed. I originally installed them with WiX with the NeverOverwrite setting and then realized they may get uninstalled so I added Permanent to them in a later version.  Now the Windows Installer Resiliency check on startup of the program is starting a configuration when users open the program and I think maybe it's because I added that permanent parameter, or some users modified the template, or a combination of the two. Running the repair fixes the issue, but it's happening on a lot of users machines (not all users though, and I can't consistently reproduce the issue on my own computer).

Regardless, I don't really want the installer to track these files. I just want it to not overwrite them if they exist, and not uninstall them. I don't need resiliency for them as it's just complicating things. Is there an easy way to just copy files with WiX Toolset?

Answer (score 0):

***Application Launch***: The usual way to deal with this is to install the templates to a read-only location and then have your application copy them to the user profile for each user on first launch. This way the user-specific and changed files are never tracked by Windows Installer.

---

Previous answers on this topic or related topics:

- [Wix deferred custom action access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010435/wix-deferred-custom-action-access-denied/51010726#51010726)
- [Create a .config folder in the user folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695746/create-a-config-folder-in-the-user-folder/48697347#48697347)
- [Create folder and file on Current user profile, from Admin Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189243/create-folder-and-file-on-current-user-profile-from-admin-profile/48196886#48196886)
- [Make WIX installer place files in AppData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589789/make-wix-installer-place-files-in-appdata/52600747#52600747)