# WiX Shortcuts Not Detecting Files In Application Directory

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Part of my application needs to read a config file, which I keep in the same directory as my application's exe. My issue is that the shortcuts created by WiX don't find this file.

I can create my shortcuts post install, and they work, but I would rather fix this issue instead of doing that.

This is what my component looks like:

```
<Component Id="MyApp.exe" Guid="G-U-I-D">
    <File Id="MyApp.exe" Name="MyApp.exe" Source="$(var.MyApp_TargetDir)MyApp.exe">
      <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="My Application" Icon="Icon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
      <Shortcut Id="StartMenuShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="My App" Icon="Icon.ico" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: If I understand your comment correctly, I am wondering if you simply do not set the shortcut's **`WorkingDirectory`** attribute?

***WiX Markup Sample***:

```
<Directory Id="MyDir" Name="My Dir">

  <Component Id="My.exe" Feature="Main">
    <File Source="My.exe">
      <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut"
                Directory="DesktopFolder"
                Name="My Product"
                Advertise="yes"

                WorkingDirectory="MyDir">
       </Shortcut>
    </File>
  </Component>

</Directory>
```

***Shortcut Properties***:

[image: Shortcut Properties]

---

If this is a settings file that you intend to write to you should put it in the user profile so that it is writeable for the launching user. Your `application.exe` file should be able to find the config file regardless if it is in your application installation folder or in the user profile?

***C# mockup*** (should use **`Path.Combine`**, but this is just for illustration):

```cs
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\MyFolder\MyFile.xml";
```

Is there a specific need to specify the file path in the shortcuts?

---

***Some Links***:

- [Various ways to deal with config files and writeability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files/50588465#50588465).

Comment: Not a settings file, it's a read only xml file. And to clarify, my application.exe finds it. I can, after installing, create shortcuts for my application and put them anywhere on my PC, and launching through a shortcut works. It's just when I use the shortcuts created during the installation process that the issue comes up.

Comment: Please check the new top section of the answer - see if that helps.