# How to handle configurations while updating the installer using WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm still newbie with Wix and exploring it! I had made a installer "abc.msi" which is working fine. After installing the abc.msi I go to folder and update my configuration file say it ".env" manually with respect to servers. Now when I update the installer and installs the new "abc.msi" the ".env" gets overridden with new values.

What I'm looking for ".env" shouldn't get removed and updated newly. It should restore the value which I've updated manually plus should get the new values from the installer.

Comment: [Please skim this answer from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286717/msi-installer-revert-the-modified-installation-files-if-application-starts-with) - see if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a job for a custom action, since configuring the files to not be replaced is not enough, you also want them to be updated with the new values on upgrade.

Paid tools, like Advanced Installer and others, have built-in support for this, so you don't have to write any code. For example, if your settings file is an XML one you can use the XML locator support from Advanced Installer, here are two tutorials with some examples:

- [Load installer property from config file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-load-installer-property-from-configuration-file.html)
- [XML Locator tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-XML-locator.html) - multiple examples

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: I'm looking something which Wix can help me.

Comment: I noticed that is I why I said in the first paragraph that it seems like something that might require custom code - i.e. a custom action. From my knowledge, Wix doesn't provide this type of built-in functionality. More on DTF custom actions for Wix: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html