# Wix ServiceInstall specify account

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, account

I created a service installer with WiX. The setup runs with `InstallPrivileges="elevated"`. My service has to access a distant folder, so I want to specify the user attribute to be sure that the service will have sufficient privileges.

I checked the WiX documentation but I only found how to define local system as account.

How can I define a user for the service (maybe the current user)?

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Vital="yes"
                Name="$(var.service)"
                DisplayName="$(var.product)"
                Start="auto"
                Account="LocalSystem"
                ErrorControl="normal" />
```

Comment: You should define "distant folder", is it a network folder? A share name? It seems that you've decided the solution is to give the service a set of credentials, but the problem of accessing a "distant folder" is not well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Credentials***: You need to specify an account and a password, maybe something like show below (no time to test right now). Note that public properties can be set when installing from the command line using **`msiexec.exe`** or via **MSI dialogs**:

```
<..>

<Property Id="SERVICEACCOUNT" Hidden="yes" Value="MyUser"/>
<Property Id="SERVICEPASSWORD" Hidden="yes" Value="MyPass"/>

<..>

<Component>

   <ServiceInstall Name="MyService" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Type="ownProcess"
                   Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" >
   </ServiceInstall>

   <ServiceControl Name="MyService" Start="install" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" />

</Component>
```

***Create Local Users***: If you need to create local users on the machine you install on, you can use the WiX Util features. [**Perhaps see this sample on github**](https://github.com/namoamitabha/WiXLab/blob/44cf2a57f7990cb1528a415e2d219c2eb0a98a56/Lab-Basic/Final/WiXDemo.Setup/Product.wxs). Search for `"util:User"`.

---

***Mandatory preaching :-)***: Personally I don't like services running with user credentials - both for **`security reasons`** and for **`practical reasons`** (managing the password change process without causing major service disruptions).

More in **`Section 12`** here: [How do I avoid common design flaws in my WiX / MSI deployment solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution/45840087#45840087) Please check the links as well - maybe particularly on "***[managed service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts)***"? ([step-by-step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10))).

---

***Some Links***:

- [ServiceInstall](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html)
- [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html)