# Wix msi installer is removing then installing the service again which i have to re-enter credentials

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a problem when i do upgrade for my service using wix (msi) installer the service created in services is removed then created from scratch which forgets about the credentials put in "log on" tab which is normal...

Is there any way to prevent removing/creating of the service during upgrade? just replace binaries and don't touch the service?

example code to create the service:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="TheID" Name="TheName"
    DisplayName="The Name" Type="ownProcess"
    Interactive="no" Start="auto" Vital="yes" ErrorControl="normal"
    Description="description">
    <util:ServiceConfig  FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" />
</ServiceInstall>
```

Comment: [Please check sections 5 and 12 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution/45840087#45840087).

Comment: Do you only have one service and will it never change once created?

Comment: at this point yes... if there is a way for now we can calculate the downside for the future versions